# JSON file in CRUD table in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

i am working on CRUD table with javascript codes. i get the data of table from external JSON file. i have one question:
how can i delete one row in table and that row in JSON file deletes at same time?
it means update the data in json file automatically.
thanks a lot

Comment: On the client, just remove the element from the JSON array and at the same time send a request to some service to change the file. On the server, just overwrite the file completely with a new JSON string. What framework or language are you running on the server side?

Comment: i am not using any server side language. i am new in javascript and i want to know that its possible to do that in client side or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible client-side, it's just not only a couple lines like it would be with a node.js service.

The easiest method I can think of at the moment is using a hyperlink to download the new file:

```js
// source data
const data = [
  { "id": 1, "cols": [
    { "id": 1, "val": "row 1 col 1" },
    { "id": 2, "val": "row 1 col 2" },
    { "id": 3, "val": "row 1 col 3" },
    { "id": 4, "val": "row 1 col 4" },
    { "id": 5, "val": "row 1 col 5" }
  ]},
  { "id": 2, "cols": [
    { "id": 6, "val": "row 2 col 1" },
    { "id": 7, "val": "row 2 col 2" },
    { "id": 8, "val": "row 2 col 3" },
    { "id": 9, "val": "row 2 col 4" },
    { "id": 10, "val": "row 2 col 5" }
  ]},
  { "id": 3, "cols": [
    { "id": 11, "val": "row 3 col 1" },
    { "id": 12, "val": "row 3 col 2" },
    { "id": 13, "val": "row 3 col 3" },
    { "id": 14, "val": "row 3 col 4" },
    { "id": 15, "val": "row 3 col 5" }
  ]}
];
// create a new dataset by rmoving the 3rd row
const removed_row = data.filter( row => row.id !== 3 );
// create a uri for the object
const data_uri = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify( removed_row ));
const data_name = "myJSON";
// create a hyperlink we can click to download the file
const anchor = document.createElement( 'a' );
anchor.href = data_uri;
anchor.download = `${ data_name }.json`;
// append, click and remove the anchor so the download is triggered
document.body.appendChild( anchor );
anchor.click();
anchor.remove();
```

One downside is that you'll be limited in file size. Once you go over a certain limit, this won't work anymore. If you need like large JSON files several megabytes big, you'd probably better look for s serverside solution.